# How to set the starting point when using the Redis scan command in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce

i want to migrate 70million data redis(sentinel-mode) to redis(cluster-mode)

```
ScanOptions options = ScanOptions.scanOptions().build();
Cursor<byte[]> c = sentinelTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().scan(options);

while(c.hasNext()){
        count++;
        String key = new String(c.next());
        key = key.trim();
        String value = (String)sentinelTemplate.opsForHash().get(key,"tc");
        //Thread.sleep(1);
        clusterTemplate.opsForHash().put(key, "tc", value);

    }
```

I want to scan again from a certain point because redis connection disconnected at some point.

How to set the starting point when using the Redis scan command in spring boot?

Moreover, whenever the program is executed using the above code, the connection is broken when almost 20 million data are moved.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue you're currently facing?

Comment: When the program is executed using the above code, the redis connection is broken when almost 20 million data are moved. i can get last scan position using cursor.getposition method so, i want know how to scan with start position

Comment: You can't. Because redis template doesn't offer cursor.getposition, also because  when you start scanning, it has to do with your current session. If you lost connection and connect again, a new scanning will be different from your previous one.  However, I suggest you use RDB to transfer this amount of data. Take a look at this : https://fnordig.de/2014/03/11/redis-cluster-with-pre-existing-data/